# javascript - How to zoom an image over the mouse position and display result on div

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

I'm trying to zoom an image and display the result on a div that's around the cursor, something like [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_image_zoom) does, except they display the result on another image and "I'm not".

The problem is, the zoom is not exactly right with respect to the mouse cursor, it's displaying the closest pixels but not the right ones, and I can't figure out why.

Here's the [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/Dogmaflow/pobgq2da/3/).

My CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-zoom-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-zoom-lens {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

.img-zoom-result {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.crosshair {
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Image Zoom</h1>

<p>Mouse over the image:</p>

<div class="img-zoom-container crosshair">
  <img id="myimage" src="https://www.pasionfutbol.com/__export/1506450064123/sites/pasionlibertadores/img/2017/09/26/puyol3c.jpg_715985292.jpg">
  <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result"></div>
</div>

<p>The image must be placed inside a container with relative positioning.</p>
<p>The result can be put anywhere on the page, but must have the class name "img-zoom-result".</p>
<p>Make sure both the image and the result have IDs. These IDs are used when a javaScript initiates the zoom effect.</p>
```

The JS:

```
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  lens.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  lens.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    lens.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}

imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
```

As you see is a copy-paste code from w3schools, but I need to do the changes I've explained above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the position in the zoomed image.

```
/*display what the lens "sees":*/
var lw=lens.offsetWidth;
var lh=lens.offsetHeight;
// taking here the pos.x of event and scale it with zoom factor , then subtract the lense width divided by zoom factor;
// then some fine tuning : subtracting the 0.5 lense width in the zoomed image 
// UPDATED
var zx=pos.x*cx -(0.5*lw) ; 
var zy=pos.y*cy -(0.5*lh) ; 
lens.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (zx) + "px -" + (zy) + "px";
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Works very fine, thanks! But I have a question. Can you explain me the formula of zx and zy? I still don't know why it works and I would like to do. @Vitalis

Comment: Explanation to long for the comment section, I`ll add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your mouse event lives in the original space of the image. 
Let`s say you have an image that has the dimensions of 200x200 px.

Your lense applies a zooming transformation on the original image using the zooming factor
Let`s assume your zooming factor 4 and is constant in x and y  directions.
So your zoomed image is 800x800 px ;

When the mouse cursor is at position 100x100 in the original image, so it will be 
at position 400x400 in the zoomed image.

So the first part of the equation for zoomedX (zx) and zoomdY (zy) is to 
scale the cursor position with the zoom factor 
zx=pos.x* cx, where pos.x == cursor position in the original image and cx is the scale factor (here 4)

The next step is to shift the zoomed position for the lens size.
However, your lense size lives in the original scale space.
Let's say you lense has the dimensions 70x70 in the original space.

We need to transform the lense dimensions into the scaled space.
If the original area is 70x70 in the zoomed image, it will be less (17.5*17.5)

So we have the second part of the equation (lw/cx), where lw is the lens width and cx the scale factor.

Additionally, while writing this, I have found an error in my equation (it was already late yesterday ;) )

The last step is that we need to translate the position to the center of the zoomed image
You did this in the original space (x- 0.5* lenseWidth), 
However, It has to happen in the scaled space, so 0.5*cx

```
//   scaled X  - half scaled zoom factor * upscaled lense size
zx=pos.x*cx -(0.5*cx)* (lw/cx) ; 
zy=pos.y*cy -(0.5*cy)* (lh/cy) ;


// re evaluation the eq :
zx=pos.x*cx -(0.5*lw) ; 
zy=pos.y*cy -(0.5*lh) ;
```

In comparison to you previsous equation : 
zx= x* cx <==> zx= (pos.x - 0.5 lw) * cx 
The lense transiotion was also scaled before

I hope this helps :)

It should also now be accurate to the selected pixel.

Comment: Took a couple of readings to understand it all, but was an amazing explanation. I think I would'nt solved this problem without your help I'm very grateful, and yes, I've tested both solutions and this one seems to be (perfectly) more accurate with the pixels. Thanks again :D . @Vitalis